# About how to get GarbageCollectorMXBean

Tags: java, jmx

I find two ways to get all GarbageCollectorMXBeans from JVM,

First

`ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` which described from [JAVA API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html)

Second

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> beans = new ArrayList<GarbageCollectorMXBean>();
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName gcName = new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.GARBAGE_COLLECTOR_MXBEAN_DOMAIN_TYPE + ",*");
for (ObjectName name : server.queryNames(gcName, null))
{
    GarbageCollectorMXBean gc = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server, name.getCanonicalName(), GarbageCollectorMXBean.class);
    beans.add(gc);
}
```

I want to know any differences between these two?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. The first variant is just a shortcut for the second one.